# Pricing 5Y US treasury day count convention

Tags: bond, daycounting

I am trying to price a simple 5Y US T Bill. The pricing should be fairly straightforward, however my result is still off by a significant amoaunt. I think the daycount fraction is incorrect, but I am not able to fix it.

I am using an ACT/ACT day convention. Please also notice that one of the payment for a a coupon takes place on the 29th of Feb. I think the LEAP YEAR also makes things harder.

[image]

I Calculated the YEAR fractions in two ways:
 - DAYS(d1,sett)/DAYS(d1,d2)*2
 - Excel YEARFRAC(settlement, coupon)

Comment: Did you account for accrued interest?

Comment: I should have made it clear. This is a clean price calculation.

Comment: Try changing the coupon to 0.33 to see if you get par?